# Designing Domain model

Tags: uml

I have scenerio like librarian searches for the phone in the computer directory, selects student id and retreives the student record. After that she updates and saves the record. How could I draw the domain model for it.
The objects would be:
1) Librarian
2) Computer Directory
3) Student Record
What else? How would I represent all the associations?

Comment: Please don't ask exactly the same question twice. Remove http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198543/domain-models-and-uml and in future just edit what you have already created.

Comment: Have you tried it? You can try a class diagram. Show some effort before asking for the solution.

Comment: From the description I assume he stuck after discovering just few potential classes.

Answer (score 2):

A domain model represents actual business logic ignoring any system behind. For instance while you might have a directory (or register) of students, it didn't matter if it's a computer system or data written on small sheets of paper.

A common method to start creating the domain is to underline all nouns in the written down description of business. They are potential names for your classes and attributes. Similarly verbs will be your potential names for associations and operations.

Next step is to decide what is the role of each underlined object and logic between them. Based on that you define your classes and their attributes. Note that sometimes the name will not be exactly the same as the one initially written down. In your example you should use `register of students` rather than `computer directory`. Also some names might not be needed at all or you might discover something that is missing in writing, but you can guess that from logic.

Note that even though it's not explicitly listed, you have a student in your business environment (linked to a Student Record, association might be named represents). Also you can clearly see that Student Record is a part of Register of Students (it'll pose a composite aggregation that might be discouraged at system level but definitely can be used on such business level) finally Student Record should have attributes id and phone.